# Store data to a variable or key-value pair and re-use it while required using Cypress

Tags: asynchronous, cypress

I need to store value retrieved during run-time in a variable or key-value pair to re-use it when required.

**Script1.ts:**
getText();

**Script2.ts:**

```js
    import {Department} from "../Script3";
    let departDetails = new Department();
```

Also, it has the method below.

```js
    getText(){
    
        cy.get('app-screen').find('input[id="studentName"]').invoke('val').as('name')
        cy.get('@name').then((name: any) => {
          cy.log('Student Name: ' + name)
          departDetails.myMap.set('Student Name', name);
          departDetails.studentName = name;
        })
        cy.log('Student Name:' + departDetails.myMap.get('Student Name');
        cy.log('Student Name:' + departDetails.studentName;
    }
```

**Script3.ts:**

```js
    export class Department{
        public myMap = new Map();
        public studentName = '';
    
        getDeptCode(){
        }
    
        getClassName(){
        }
    }
```

When I execute 'Script1.ts' from test runner, I am able to see the student name printed as 'Viola' for first cy.log in 'Script2.ts'.
For 2nd log statement, the value is not fetched from the map. It says undefined.

```js
    Student Name: undefined
```

For the 3rd log statement, the value is empty.

Why this is occurring? How do I store data in a variable or key-value pair and use it later during execution in cypress without storing in any file?

Comment: How are you importing `script3` in `script2` ?

Comment: I have edited and included the import statement in Script2.ts

Comment: import {Department} from "../Script3";

Comment: cy.log(departDetails.myMap) provides {}.

Comment: `cy.log('Student Name:' + departDetails.studentName)` takes the value before the test runs, that is before `cy.get('@name').then(...` runs, but it logs that value after the other commands.